# How to pass in a variable when setting state in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to not hard code the name of this state so I can dynamically generate some components. So far, this will not work:

```
handleChange(e) {
    var name = e.target.name
    console.log(name)
    var data = !this.state.name // trying, unsuccessfully, to pass in the 'name' variable here.
    this.setState({[name]: data});
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

The component that calls this function is a checkbox, so its using a true/false to toggle the value.

```
<Checkbox
    className="january"
    label="january"
    name="january"
    checked={this.state.january}
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
    theme="success"
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
var data = !this.state.name
```

should be

```
var data = !this.state[name]
```

What you were doing was accesing to the property "name" of the state.